# Convert list to map in flutter

Tags: flutter

I need to send some data to api in flutter but it keeps showing error.

**This is how the data format should be (this is from swagger)**

```
[
  {
    
    "availabilityId": 11
  },
{
    
    "availabilityId": 8
  }
]
```

**This is How I am sending**

```
var distinctList = _selectedId.toSet().toList();
AvaibalityId = { for (var item in distinctList) '$item'};
aId = AvaibalityId!.toList();
print ('aId');
[16, 17, 8] // this is print
```

**This is my api class**

```
final response = await _dio.patch(
        'users/my-availabilities',
        data: [
          {
            'availabilityId': availabilityId,
          }
        ],
      );
```

I think I need to convert it to map then send it, but how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map the list of data into the list of map as following

```
final list = [11, 8];
final map = list.map((e)=> {"availabilityId": e}).toList();
print(map);
```

Output:

```
[{availabilityId: 11}, {availabilityId: 8}]
```